# Replace R1C1 type formula to a named range formula in Excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I have a working VBA code (on Sheet2) that uses a Public Function to do a calculation using data on Sheet1, column B.

After I use the FillDown function to get a similar calculation for the rest of the rows.

```
Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=PERSONAL.XLSB!Scoring(Sheet1!RC2)"
Range("B2:B2", "A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
```

Public Function checks the cell and assigns a score according to the value found.

```
Public Function Scoring(str As String)

Dim check As Integer

check_str = 0

If str = "US" Then check_str = 1
If check_str = 1 Then Scoring = "1"
If check_str = 0 Then Scoring = "0"

End Function
```

My **goal is to use Named Ranges instead of R1C1 formula style** to avoid any complications if the Sheet1 column order is changed. I guess there are possibilities to loop through the named ranges, but are there any simpler ways?

The code that would be the simple approach to the issue (just replacing the R1C1 type with a reference to the column in a named range), does not work:

```
Range("B2").Formula = "=PERSONAL.XLSB!Scoring(Sheet1!Range("myRange").Columns(1))"
Range("B2:B2", "A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
```

Comment: I'd be surprised if `Range("B2:B2", "A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown` works. Can you post your function code?

Comment: What is the purpose of `Sheet1!Range("myRange").Columns(1))`? Are you trying to only refer to the first column in the named range? If so, what does the function do, and can it handle this input?

Comment: @SJR , the Public Function checks the cell and assigns a score according to the value found. (see updated - above)

Comment: (1) Your function declares `check` but then uses `check_str` and `check_ip` (but doesn't seem to do anything meaningful) (2) Please don't call a function "Function" (3) It returns a string and uses a string as a parameter so you cannot pass a range of cells.

Comment: @Plutian Yes, I am trying to refer to the first column in the named range, hoping that the FillDown will pick the appropriate row (and thus the exact cell) similar to how it works with R1C1 formula style. But is it possible at all?...

Comment: @SJR Thank you for the clarifications! I corrected the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works with the FillDown:

```
Range("B2").Formula = "=PERSONAL.XLSB!Scoring(INDEX(Sheet!myRange,ROWS($A$1:$A1),1))"
Range("B2:B2", "A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
```

Answer (score 3):

If the named range has workbook scope, your formula would be:

```
"=PERSONAL.XLSB!Function(INDEX(myRange,0,1))"
```

to refer to the first column of that range. If the name has worksheet scope, then use `Sheet1!myRange` in the formula.

Comment: `"=PERSONAL.XLSB!Function(INDEX(myRange,1,1))"` works in my case, but just for the 1st row. For all other rows after FillDown the results are the same, since `INDEX(myRange,1,1))` refers to the same cell in the named range. I guess some kind of looping is still needed then...

Comment: Why are you using `1, 1)` at the end instead of what I posted? Your version refers to the first cell in the first column. Mine refers to the entire first column.

Comment: I tried `,0,1)` version a few times and it gives me #VALUE! error in all cells of the table. However, `,1,1)` version works for the 1st row... What am I still missing?

Comment: What input does your function expect? One value or an entire column? Your original coding suggested an entire column.

Comment: It seems that the formula expects one value. `Scoring(Sheet1!RC2)` then obviously refers to a single cell. And the FillDown function changes it to `Scoring(Sheet1!R[1]C2)` - `Scoring(Sheet1!R[2]C2)` - `Scoring(Sheet1!R[3]C2)` and so forth. It seems that it does not work the same way with `Scoring(INDEX(myRange,1,1))` and some kind of looping is required.

Comment: You could use: `INDEX(myRange,1,ROWS($A$1:$A1))` which will adjust as you fill down.